# Java XMLGregorianCalendar is changing the time - Strange behavior

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a date as input = 2021-03-12T10:42:01.000Z.... and I want to transform into this format:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";


public String getDate(XMLGregorianCalendar input) {
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    input.toGregorianCalendar().setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    String output = f.format(input.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
    System.out.println(output);
}

2021-03-12T12:42:01+0200
```

Basically, it's adding 2hs more. Maybe it's related with the time zone, I didn't test it in another computer. I have 2 questions:

- Why this is happening
- What can I do to avoid it? It's a legacy app so I don't want to do a big change

Thanks

Comment: Also not that `input.toGregorianCalendar()` most likely (depending on the implementation) gives you a new instance with every call. Therefore your statement to set the timezone probably does not change anything. However, it is not the source of the different hour in the output.

Comment: Which result had you wanted? `2021-03-12T10:42:01+0000`? Your string is in UTC, denoted by the trailing `Z`. Will that always be the case, or can you have other offsets, for example `-03`, `-0100` or `+02:00`, instead?

Comment: Both your input and your output are in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so is your conversion really necessary? If the receiver of your string accepts ISO 8601, I suggest you just give them `input.toString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, it's adding 2hs more

Not really. It's giving you the output for the same instant in time, but in your system local time zone - because you're creating a `SimpleDateFormat` without specifying a time zone (or a culture):

```java
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
```

Personally I'd recommend avoiding using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` entirely, preferring the `java.time` types and formatters. But if you definitely want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, just make sure you set the time zone to UTC (assuming you always want UTC) and ideally set the culture as well (e.g. to `Locale.ROOT`).

Comment: I think I'm setting the time zone in the next line

Comment: @Julio: You're not setting it on the *formatter* though. The value you provide to the formatter is just a `java.util.Date`, which doesn't have an associated time zone - it's just an instant in time. The formatter uses whatever time zone has been set *on the formatter* to represent that instant in time.

Comment: ah ok, makes sense. Thanks so much

Comment: @Julio You need `f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));`

Comment: @Matt – What about the trailing 'Z' in the pattern? For my understanding, it is the timezone (Zulu = UTC).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it worked. Thanks Matt

Comment: @tquadrat Yes, the timezone on `input` is most likely already defined since the trailing `Z` is shown. This is valid under the assumption that the implementation (`XMLGregorianCalendar` is abstract) handles this properly. In the XML-type, there is no concept of timezones. This is why we can set it explicitly or use the `#toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone, ..., ...)` method to convert in the timezone we want.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800107/642706) is correct, and smart. You appear to be seeing simply a time zone adjustment. Your two strings `2021-03-12T10:42:01.000Z` & `2021-03-12T12:42:01+0200` represent the very same moment. The 12 noon hour, if two hours ahead of UTC, is the same as 10 AM hour with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

And, as mentioned in that other Answer, you really should avoid using the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

## tl;dr

```
myXMLGregorianCalendar     // Legacy class, representing a moment as seen in some time zone.
.toGregorianCalendar()     // Another legacy class, also representing a moment as seen in some time zone.
.toZonedDateTime()         // A modern *java.time* class, representing a moment as seen in some time zone.
.toInstant()               // Another *java.time* class, for representing a moment as seen in UTC.
.truncatedTo(              // Lopping off some smaller part of the date-time value.
    ChronoUnit.SECONDS     // Specifying whole seconds as our granularity of truncation, so lopping off any fractional second.
)                          // Returns another `Instant` object, rather than altering (mutating) the original, per immutable objects pattern.
.toString()                // Generating text representing the content of our `Instant` object, using standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted `SimpleDateFormat`, `XMLGregorianCalendar` , `GregorianCalendar`, and such.

### Convert legacy <——> modern

You can easily convert from the legacy types to *java.time*. Look for new `to`/`from` methods on the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
```

### Adjust to offset of zero

Adjust from whatever time zone to UTC by extracting an `Instant`. This class represents a moment as seen in UTC, always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Understand that `zdt` and `instant` both represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but differ in their wall-clock time.

## Truncation

Given the formatting pattern seen in your Question, you seem want to work with a granularity of whole seconds. To lop off any fractional second, truncate to seconds.

```
Instant truncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

Your desired text format is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard is used by default in *java.time* for parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify any formatting pattern.

```
String output = truncated.toString() ;
```

Comment: This is the way forward. The OP needs the string in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` format. It would be useful for him and future visitors if you add a section regarding the format.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for offering a suggestion. But I don’t know what you mean specifically. What more is there to say beyond my last paragraph?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you for the suggestion. I added code and prose explaining truncation to whole seconds.